# Lexicographic sorting in java?

Tags: java, sorting, compareto, lexicographic

I am trying to sort 3 strings alphabetically using the compareTo method in java without using arrays.

Is the fastest way to do this by setting up 6 compare statements and sorting by least to greatest or is there any easier way? Thanks!

Comment: Why six comparisons? Wouldn't three be enough?

Comment: Is the use of `Collections` allowed, if not arrays?!

Answer (score 0):

put it into `TreeSet`.

```
  TreeSet<String> t = new TreeSet<>();
  t.add("stack");
  t.add("over");
  t.add("flow");
  System.out.println(t);
```

**OutPut:**

```
[flow, over, stack]
```